# publish:end:remote Event Does Not Seem to be Firing on CD Servers

Tags: publishing

My code is below. The Log.Info functions are being called and writing to the log on my CM box. But, nothing is being logged on the CD servers.

Sitecore 8.1 Update 3

**XML Code:**

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <events timingLevel="custom">
      <event name="publish:end">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapHandler, Sitemap.XML" method="RefreshSitemap" />
      </event>
      <event name="publish:end:remote">
        <handler type="Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapHandler, Sitemap.XML" method="RefreshSitemap" />
      </event>
    </events>
  </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

**C# Code:**

```
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using System;

namespace Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML
{
    public class SitemapHandler
    {
        public void RefreshSitemap(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Log.Info("SitemapXML Module - RefreshSitemap Function Has Been Started", this);

            SitemapManager sitemapManager = new SitemapManager();
            sitemapManager.SubmitSitemapToSearchenginesByHttp();
            //sitemapManager.RegisterSitemapToRobotsFile();


            Log.Info("SitemapXML Module - RefreshSitemap Function Has Finished", this);

        }
    }
}
```

**ShowConfig.xml:**

```
<event name="publish:end:remote">
  <handler type="Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapHandler, Sitemap.XML" method="RefreshSitemap" patch:source="SitemapXML.config" />
</event>
```

**Log File Error (Possibly Related):**

```
Heartbeat 2017:04:17 17:19:10 ERROR One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'publish:end:remote' event.
Exception[1]: System.NullReferenceException 
Message[1]: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. 
Source[1]: MyCompany.Framework 
   at MyCompany.Framework.Pipelines.CustomLinkProvider.CustomLinkProvider.GetItemUrl(Item item, UrlOptions options) in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\MyCompany.Framework\Pipelines\CustomLinkProvider\CustomLinkProvider.cs:line 15
   at Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapManager.GetItemUrl(Item item, Site site, Language language) in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\SitempXML\SitemapXML\SitemapManager.cs:line 306
   at Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapManager.BuildSitemapItem(XmlDocument doc, Item item, Site site) in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\SitempXML\SitemapXML\SitemapManager.cs:line 257
   at Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapManager.BuildSitemapXML(List`1 items, Site site) in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\SitempXML\SitemapXML\SitemapManager.cs:line 230
   at Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapManager.WriteInXml(List`1 items, Site site, Int32 skip, Int32 take, String fullPath) in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\SitempXML\SitemapXML\SitemapManager.cs:line 74
   at Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapManager.BuildSiteMap(String sitename, String sitemapUrlNew) in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\SitempXML\SitemapXML\SitemapManager.cs:line 105
   at Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapManager..ctor() in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\SitempXML\SitemapXML\SitemapManager.cs:line 65
   at Sitecore.Modules.SitemapXML.SitemapHandler.RefreshSitemap(Object sender, EventArgs args) in E:\Agents\PRG01\_work\5\s\Features\UpgradeToSitecore8.1\Source\SitempXML\SitemapXML\SitemapHandler.cs:line 30
   at Sitecore.Events.Event.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result)
```

**Update:**
I am now seeing the logging on each CD server. This issue seemed to be that I have to browse at least one page on the each CD server. Maybe the issue is that the application needs to be started.

Comment: Have you checked out the scaling configurations?

Comment: They should be fine. What do I need to double check? Each CD server has a unique instance name.

Comment: Have you reviewed this? ScalabilitySettings.config is often overlooked. https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/xdb/configuring_servers/configure_a_content_delivery_server

Comment: My settings are correct. The problem is more elusive.

Comment: Nullref is happening in your custom link provider. You should either debug it or disable

Comment: @AndreyBobrov Can you give me any more advice? These are remote servers. How am I supposed to "debug" them? Also, what am I supposed to disable?

Comment: @ADH is your question now solved as you are seeing the events running on the CD servers?

Comment: @RichardSeal Yes, it is solved.

Comment: @RichardSeal I also think it is the solution to this question as well. https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/3932/publishing-xml-sitemaps-to-two-content-delivery-servers